# Counting nodes in binary search tree

Tags: c++

I need to create a recursive method that takes as a parameter the root node of a binary search tree. This recursive method will then return the int value of the total number of nodes that have one left descendant.

```
int Tree::leftPtrCount(int count) {
    return leftPtrCountHelper(rootPtr, count);
}
int Tree::leftPtrCountHelper(TreeNode *node, int count){
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;
    if (node->leftPtr != NULL && node->rightPtr == NULL)
        count++;
    else
        return leftPtrCountHelper(node->leftPtr, count) + leftPtrCountHelper(node->rightPtr, count);
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: You don't return the counter in all cases, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and I guess that this is one of the problems you might be having). In fact, the counter is not needed at all.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! This site has some etiquette that should be respected. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to help improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the assignment then the function will look as

```
size_t Tree::leftPtrCountHelper( const TreeNode *node )
{
    if ( node == NULL ) return 0;
    return ( node->leftPtr != NULL && node->rightPtr == NULL ) +
             leftPtrCountHelper( node->leftPtr ) + 
             leftPtrCountHelper( node->rightPtr );
}
```